# How can I invert y = pow(x, z) to get x?

Tags: python, math, logarithm, pow, square-root

As I know there is no build-in functions to do this directly, so log()? or a simple math shortcut like:

```
z = y ** (1/x)
```

x?

Comment: Be careful with 1/z. If z is int, then 1/z is actually 0. Use float instead

Comment: @ilovecp3 Not in Python 3, though it is good to be careful.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be careful, also Python 3.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `y=pow(x,z)` then `x = pow(y,1.0/z)`:

```
>>> y = pow(3,1.7)
>>> y
6.473007839923779
>>> pow(y,1.0/1.7)
3.0
```